# How can I check whether a define-style string macro is defined in CA65?

Tags: 6502, ca65

I have spent hours trying to figure out how to get conditional include paths functional in CA65 (or really, any conditional string values at all). Is it even possible?

What I want is to be able to define a constant string (which has to be a `.DEFINE` due to limitations in CA65) that is the path exclusively for configuration includes for a reusable library. I cannot find a way to define these values via the command line (the `-D VALUE=123` format does not work for strings since it uses the standard `VALUE = 123` format), nor have I found a way to detect if a .DEFINE has already been defined in the actual .inc/.asm/.s files via `.DEFINED` or `.DEFINEDMACRO` or any other means to use a default config directory or error if it wasn't specified.

For example, assume my structure is:

```
MyFile.asm
Config/String.inc
Library/String.asm
Library/Config/String.inc
```

In this example, `Config/String.inc` is my custom configuration file that I want `Library/String.asm` to use. However, I want to be able to add code to `Library/String.asm` to set the configuration directory to `Config/` *OR* output a fatal error and immediately exit if a configuration directory is not defined. Since I have not figured out a way to pass the directory and also detect it, I can only currently just blindly use the configuration directory constant/macro (which, if not used, outputs a crap-ton of errors due to the missing include) or hard-code it to use a specific directory, which is definitely not ideal.

How do I set it up so my files can include library files and override the path for them (or have a fatal error) for including config files?

If I use:

```
.DEFINE CONFIGPATH "../Config/"
.IFNDEF CONFIGPATH
  .FATAL "This always happens"
.ENDIF
```

This causes:

```
2: Error: Identifier Expected
1: Note: Macro was defined here
2: Error: Unexpected trailing garbage characters
1: Note: Macro was defined here
Fatal error: User error: This always happens
```

If I use:

```
.DEFINE CONFIGPATH "../Config/"
.IF .NOT .DEFINEDMACRO(CONFIGPATH)
  .FATAL "This always happens"
.ENDIF
```

This causes:

```
2: Error: Identifier Expected
1: Note: Macro was defined here
Fatal error: User error: This always happens
```

If I try to use a macro:

```
.MACRO INCLUDECONFIGFILE includefile
  .INCLUDE .CONCAT("../Config/", .STRING(includefile))
.ENDMACRO
```

CA65 just immediately runs the .INCLUDE, even if I never use the macro, and complains about an invalid string parameter since includefile doesn't actually exist at that point. I can actually detect this macro with `.DEFINEDMACRO`, but that does me no good since it doesn't work.

Trying to use a standard macro to just output a string also doesn't work.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my reading of [the ca65 manual](https://cc65.github.io/doc/ca65.html#ss12.9), `.define` creates definitions that are expanded before literally any other processing takes place, with the only exception being `.undefine`:

> A separate command for `.DEFINE` style macros was necessary, because the name of such a macro is replaced by its replacement list on a very low level. To get the actual name, macro replacement has to be switched off when reading the argument to `.UNDEFINE`.

Based on that wording, I would not be surprised if define-style macros were expanded immediately at the lexing stage.  This passage also implies there is no directive that checks for the existence of define-style macros: `.defined` checks for the existence of symbols, while `.definedmacro` checks for the existence of instruction-like ‘classic’ macros (those defined with `.macro`).

However, while the problem cannot be solved in full generality, it’s not all hopeless.  Since you know you intend for the macro to expand to a string, you can work around this design limitation by employing the [`.match` pseudo-function](https://cc65.github.io/doc/ca65.html#ss10.16):

```
.if .not .match(CONFIGPATH, "")
.fatal "CONFIGPATH not defined correctly!"
.endif
```

The above checks whether `CONFIGPATH` is a string token.  This can only happen if the `CONFIGPATH` token has already been expanded into its replacement token list before being received as an argument by `.match`.  If the `CONFIGPATH` is defined to expand to something else than a string, the above will behave the same as if the macro was not defined.

Comment: This actually works! Boy that is confusing. It seems that by using `.IF .MATCH(CONFIGPATH, "")` is the equivalent of a non-existent `.IF .ISSTRING(CONFIGPATH)` operation.

Comment: Since .`isstring` is non-existent, you can imagine it having any semantics whatsoever, including having it launch NetHack, in which case it would not be equivalent… but whatever helps you.

Comment: I don't see how it is illogical to expect an `.ISSTRING` to exist in an assembler that has a clear distinction between a string and a non-string. If you don't believe me, try using `.CONCAT` without converting values via `.STRING` or `.SPRINTF` or the equivalent. It's even in the same format as other commands, such as `.ISMNEMONIC`.

Comment: Sure, but I still find it funny to explain the behaviour of a directive that exists in terms of another directive that doesn’t exist and hasn’t been defined by anyone. For completeness, one would have to also describe how that non-existent directive would behave were it to exist (language is arbitrary after all, you can’t presume you understand something just by knowing its name), in which case, why not cut out the middleman?